# How can I transfer images from a Canon DSLR to a Windows phone?

Tags: file-transfer, nokia, windows-phone

I currently have an Android phone and a 6D.

Currently, on my Android I can copy pics from the camera to the phone through several ways.

```
1. Canon EOS app. (wifi)
2. DSLR controller (wifi+wired)
3. USB OTG (wired) [The Samsung phone picks up the camera and loads it as another folder in the gallary.
4. DLNA (wifi)
5. Memory card on a card reader through USB OTG onto the phone.
```

I am interested on going Nokia and am wondering what my options are.
I currently suspect that the only option I'll have on the Nokia of transferring pics from the camera to the phone is through the use of some DLNA app. I'm sure there'll be some for WP8.

Does anyone konw whether #3 or #5 works on a Lumia 820 (or other WP8 phones), and if so, which phone is that?

Comment: Apropos of nothing, _why_ are you interested in 'going Nokia'? _Why_?

Comment: 1. Google maps went useless when they lost My places, My maps, offline maps, rules and distance scale.
2. I hate when my android phone goes bezerk, and while on airplane mode decides to consume its battery down from 60+% overnight. Leaving me with no alarm.

Comment: It still has my places, offline maps and distance scale. Power consumption is mainly down to the screen. If you think a Nokia will be any better, you go for it! Give my regards to 1998 ;)

Comment: Yeah, turns out that they had done an update since I last updated. I see the distance scale, but it vanishes after it soon loads. I miss the ruler. Offline maps implementation is inefficient for caching large areas as I can't see what I just cached if I move the map a bit. Previously there would be a large square to indicate an already cached area. I couldn't find my places. I'll check. The power drain i've experienced twice is not due to large screen. Phone was freeshly rebooted, on airplane mode, screen of, zero interaction - in an infinite loop somewhere :( Yay 1998!

Comment: It's like watching someone about to happily drive off a cliff...

Comment: Lol. I'll be sure to let you know how it goes once I'm mid-air.

Comment: Not sure if this would sit better on http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: oh wow. Wow, I didn't know that existed. These "stackexchange" keeps on expanding.

I'll ask there. thanks.

Comment: Just as a closing statement. I love my lumia 925. I'm not going android ever again. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Windows Phone 7/8 operating systems are more tightly controlled than Android.  While that makes them faster and more stable than Android, it makes them less flexible in circumstances like this.

Hardware connected options are a non-starter.  Windows Phones don't support being USB hosts (the same goes for many android handsets) so connecting the camera or a reader directly are out.  Equally the SDHC implementation in Windows Phone is not a general purpose reader a card is paired with the handset and data on the card is encrypted.

Wifi is where you will have plenty of options.  The Lumia can communicate directly with the camera over wifi if the apps are available (you can check via the [Windows Phone Store](http://www.windowsphone.com/store)).  Or it can act as a base station for tethering and you can use something like the [AirStash](http://www.airstash.com/) which has an html5 interface.

Comment: Wow. Data in the SD card is encrypted and paired? !! What was Balmer thinking?!

Thanks for the headsup about AirStash. Sounds pretty epic. 

I see some apps about DLNA on winstore. 
I guess I'll properly find out when I buy a WP8

Comment: Makes me sad since Windows Mobile was awesome because it let you have control even more easily than Android.  Guess they wanted to encrypt the card to make their DRM more secure.

Comment: The encryption behaviour is to ensure that if the handset is lost/stolen that a remote wipe makes any data on the card inaccessible.  Any DRM'd content could be stored quite happily without further encryption.

Comment: Yes, the encryption does make, "some sense" but ... sadface still.

Comment: FYI.Now i'm on my second lumia phone, this one has an SD card. The contents do not appear encrypted or paired.